Could not load blob, Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
I am currently trying to do a preview of an STL File on a web page. My code works when the url used is one from the web, for example one of three.js's example files but when I try to do it with the "handle_preview" function it doesn't work.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is to upload an stl file I made (which isn't corrupted as I can preview it using Window's 3D preview) and store it in my database. I also made sure I could download the file and that it is the right file (preview works etc). However, when I try to preview this particular file by turning it into a blob and then building a url of the blob I get this message:
ERROR
Could not load blob: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80194:36
    at Object.onLoad (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81218:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:212870:39

Where is the bug coming from? What can I do to solve it?
Thanks in advance.
Here is part of the page's code: (stack overflow wouldn't let me post all of it)
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { StlViewer } from "react-stl-viewer";
// Styled Components
const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: #ff5757;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
`;

const DocumentForm = styled.form`
margin-top 20px`;

const DocumentList = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
`;

// Reference View Component
const ReferenceView = () => {
  const { id } = useParams(); // Get the reference ID from the URL
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [reference1, setReference1] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [documentType, setDocumentType] = useState("");
  const [version, setVersion] = useState(1);
  const [previewFile, setPreviewFile] = useState(null);

  const handlePreview = (stlFile) => {
    console.log("PREVIEW");
    console.log("TYPE", stlFile.type);
    const blob = new Blob([stlFile], { type: "model/stl" });
    console.log("BLOB", blob);

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
      const bufferLength = arrayBuffer.byteLength;

      console.log("Dataview bounds (size in bytes):", bufferLength);

      const firstBytes = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(bufferLength, 10); i++) {
        firstBytes.push(dataView.getUint8(i));
      }
      console.log("First few bytes in the DataView:", firstBytes);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

    setPreviewFile(link);
  };

  const stlViewerStyle = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Display loading state
  }

  if (!reference1) {
    return <div>Reference not found</div>; // Handle case where reference is not found
  }

  const { reference } = reference1;

  const handleViewBOMDetails = () => {
    navigate(`/boms/${reference.bom._id}`);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>{console.log(reference)}</h1>
      <h1>Reference Details</h1>
      <h2>Associated Product: {reference.product.name}</h2>
      <h2>Reference code: {reference.code}</h2> {/* Display the product name */}
      <Button onClick={handleViewBOMDetails}>View BOM Details</Button>
      <DocumentForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} required />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Version"
          value={version}
          onChange={handleVersionChange}
          required
        />
        <Button type="submit">Upload Document</Button>
      </DocumentForm>
      <h3>Documents:</h3>
      {previewFile && (
        <StlViewer
          style={stlViewerStyle}
          orbitControls
          shadows
          url={previewFile}
        />
      )}
      <DocumentList>
        {documents.map((doc) => (
          <li key={doc._id}>
            {doc.filename} - Version: {doc.version}
            {doc.documentType === "model/stl" && (
              <Button onClick={() => handlePreview(doc.file)}>Preview</Button>
            )}
            <Button onClick={() => handleDownload(doc._id)}>Download</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(doc._id)}>Delete</Button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </DocumentList>
      <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</Button>{" "}
      {/* Button to go back */}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ReferenceView;


Please read carefully tag descriptions when you pick them. The C++ tag [tag:STL] is not suitable to the question content.
